# Stop GridView from putting scope attribute on every TH

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How do I stop ASP.NET's GridView from putting a scope attribute on every TH?  I am manually doing the headers and this is interfering.

Comment: Is it acceptable for you to just remove those attributes after they are rendered?

Comment: Could you explain how scope attribute is interfering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is a way. You can implement the `OnRowDataBound` or `OnRowCreated` event and change the scope value for all header cells.

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            ((DataControlFieldHeaderCell)cell).Scope = TableHeaderScope.NotSet;   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very cool, thanks!  I was trying setting the variable to "" and .Attributes.Remove("scope").